# Anime where a character works to prevent his birth

Tags: story-identification, anime

I'm trying to find an anime I watched in 2005/2006. It was a short one (probably around 12-13 episodes) and I remember only one character - a dark haired guy (his name started with Y, but I'm not sure) whose biggest dream was to never been born. The point was that he didn't want to commit suicide, but simply never exist in the first place.

All I remember from the story line is that their was another guy who fought to make the dark haired guy's dream come true. In the end, he succeeds and the other one disappears/vanishes - as he has never been born.

Truth be told it was a really sad story, but I can't stop thinking about it and as it wasn't popular I can't find its title. Unfortunately, that's all I remember.

If anyone of you maybe recognise this anime?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: http://shingekinokyojin.wikia.com/wiki/Ymir?

Comment: http://nabarinoou.wikia.com/wiki/Yoite?

Answer (score 12):

This is [Nabari No Ou](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nabari_no_Ou).

One of the main characters, [Yoite](http://nabarinoou.wikia.com/wiki/Yoite) expressed a sincere desire to not only die, but to be erased from ever having existed.

> *When Yoite turned fourteen, his family decided to kill him, slashing
>   his throat and unsuccessfully attempting to force Tsukasa to do the
>   same. **After this desperate attempt of ending his life, being erased
>   from existence became his goal**. He ran from the house and was saved by
>   Hattori, who accepted him into the Grey Wolves. **Yoite spends a year
>   studying the Kira technique and all required ninja skills. Hattori
>   promises this would bring him closer to his goal of being erased. His
>   desire to disappear comes from his painful past and his fear of death.**
>   By disappearing he wouldn't have experienced so much pain nor death.
>   Yoite is then placed under Yukimi's care and is given the name
>   "Yoite".*

[image]

Comment: That's the one! Thank you so much, you're absolutely amazing! <3

Comment: @user36109 - Don't forget to mark as "accepted" if this is the correct answer

Comment: Still not accepted :')

Comment: @Denny - OP was last seen a couple of days after getting their answer. I think the ship may well have sailed on seeing an acceptance from this one ;-)